# Drive-time isochrones HQGIS partially not drawn

Tags: qgis, drive-time-areas

I would like to draw 30 minute drive-time isochrones from the centroids of the UK's largest cities. First I tried the TravelTime plug-in, but it didn't allow me to create this many isochrones with the free version. Then I tried the HQGIS plug-in instead, and it gave the following result:

[image]

As you see, it has only drawn isochrones around some of the cities but not all. Does anyone have an idea why?